# ios: Ad Hoc app installs to iPads but not iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I built an app, and I'm distributing it for testing OTA. It is targeted for iOS 5.0 and above and is configured to be universal (so should work on both phones and tablets). It has been running just fine on both kinds of devices. Today I put out a new version. It installs just fine on tablets. However it won't install on phones running any version of the os from 5.0 up. They just get the message 'This app cannot be downloaded.' All of these users are verified provisioned. I'm not sure what I could have done between versions to keep this app from being installed on phones now. What should I be looking for as a possible issue?

It runs fine in the iPhone simulator

Comment: Building with an iPad plugged in? Check the build setting for "build active architecture only".

Comment: Nope. iPad isn't plugged in, and Build Active Architecture Only > Release is set to No.

Comment: What architectures are defined as Valid Architectures in your build settings? Are all kinds of iPhone devices (iPhone 4, 4S,5)  throwing the same error?

Comment: valid architectures listed as 'armv7 armv7s'. I'm assuming this is how it's always been as I haven't changed that.

Comment: Are you using TestFlightApp ? It might be an error on their end

Comment: How did you get the device UDIDs? If you used a utility like "Adhoc Helper" on iOS 7 beta, it now returns phony UDIDs unfortunately and you'll get that error.

Comment: I'm not using TestFlight, and I got the UDID's by having each person get it from iTunes. I know the UDID's work because they used to be able to run the app. It's only after a recent build that this problem popped up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any of the iPhones the app won't install on, you can connect it to xcode and view the device logs for why the installation failed. 
That'll give you the most definitive answer.

If you can't access the iPhones, I would say you should regenerate your IPA file and make sure the target you're building the IPA for has the right configs (universal app, iOS version, provisioning profile assignments etc.)

Comment: I did have access. Nothing shows up in either the device log or the console. I have also tried rebuilding the IPA.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this helped, but I decided to export the ipa with a new file name this time. I didn't modify any settings in the package anywhere other than giving the .ipa file a new name. Doing that fixed it. Now everyone can download it again.